# Retrieving Data from DB2 Using pyodbc

Tags: python, flask, db2, pyodbc, db2-400

I am trying to retrieve data from an DB2 using pyodbc and print it in JSON using Python. I have 2 different func.

This one's works :

```
import flask
from flask import flash, request, Flask, jsonify
import pyodbc

@app.route('/api/acrdkl/filter', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():

    dkkdcb = request.args.get('dkkdcb')
    dkblrg = request.args.get('dkblrg')
    dkthrg = request.args.get('dkthrg')

    query = """select trim(dkkdcb), trim(dkkdps), trim(dkcob), trim(dkureg), trim(dkbktg), trim(dkblrg), trim(dkthrg)
    from simdta.ACRDKL WHERE dkkdcb = param_dkkdcb and dkblrg = param_dkblrg and dkthrg = param_dkthrg"""

    print("Dkkdcb ", dkkdcb)
    print("Dkblrg ", dkblrg)
    print("Dkthrg ", dkthrg)

    query = query.replace("param_dkkdcb", dkkdcb)
    query = query.replace("param_dkblrg", dkblrg)
    query = query.replace("param_dkthrg", dkthrg)
    print("Query 1 ", query)

    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=AS400;UID=.....;PWD=....")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    results = []
    for dt in rows:
        print("DT ", dt)
        print("dkkdcb: ", dt[0])
        print("dkkdps: ", dt[1])
        print("dkcob: ", dt[2])
        print("dkureg: ", dt[3])
        print("dkbktg: ", dt[4])
        print("dkblrg: ", dt[5])
        print("dkthrg: ", dt[6])
        
        print("\n")
        results.append([x for x in dt])
    return jsonify(results)
```

But when I tried this one's using `try-except`:

```
@app.route('/api/acrdkl/filter2', methods=['GET'])
def filter2():
    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=AS400;UID=....;PWD=....")
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        sql= """select 
        trim(dkkdcb), trim(dkkdps), trim(dkcob), trim(dkureg), trim(dkbktg), trim(dkblrg), trim(dkthrg)
        from simdta.ACRDKL where dkkdcb=? and dkblrg=? and dkthrg=?"""
        data=(int(ardkkdcb), month, year)
        cursor.execute(sql, 1402, 10, 2020)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        result = []
        for dt in rows:
            print("dkkdcb: ", dt[0])
            print("dkkdps: ", dt[1])
            print("dkcob: ", dt[2])
            print("dkureg: ", dt[3])
            print("dkbktg: ", dt[4])
            print("dkblrg: ", dt[5])
            print("dkthrg: ", dt[6])
            
            print("\n")
            result.append([x for x in dt])
        return json.dumps(result)
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

It gives me this error :

```
('22023', '[22023] [Microsoft][ODBC DB2 Driver]Data exception - SQLSTATE 22023, SQLCODE -302. SQLSTATE: 22023, SQLCODE: -302 (-302) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Am I missing something in the second func? If there is a better way to solve would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first query uses literal values, the second query uses host-variables. Quite different. Db2 -302 sqlcode says that a value for one of the host-variables is too large for its datatype. Normally that is caused by a programming mistake. Check your Db2-column-datatypes and verify the actual values being bound during cursor.execute().

Comment: Hey, I've checked the datatype in my db and matched it to the variables, and still got no luck. It should be work shouldnt it?

Comment: Debugging required. We can't do it for you. trace the pyodbc and the microsoft driver to see what's happening under the covers.  If you are unable to debug, break the problem down, try first with only 1 host variable, and extend until you see what breaks it.

Comment: Ah damn. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can also explicitly cast the parameter-markers to the correct column data-type (instead of `?` use `cast(? as ...)`  )

Comment: Wait you can use that? I didnt know that before. Do you have any docs?

Comment: CAST  is part of the SQL standard. Use your documentation. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcast.htm